# I want to delete a row from a flask db.execute query based on a condition within the row

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

In flask I have this query pulled from an sqlite3 database:

```
   rows = db.execute("SELECT SUM(shares), symbol, FROM portfolio GROUP BY symbol")
```

Which outputs this:

```
[{'SUM(shares)': 0, 'symbol': 'F'}, {'SUM(shares)': 4, 'symbol': 'FB'}, {'SUM(shares)': 3, 'symbol': 'GOOG'}]
```

If the "SUM(shares)" == 0 I want to delete/remove a row in rows.  I tried this:

```
for row in rows:
    if row["SUM(shares)"] == 0:
        del(row)
```

But it is not working correctly. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a different approach: don't select them in the first place. From the [sqlite doc:](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset)

> If a HAVING clause is specified, it is evaluated once for each group
> of rows as a boolean expression. If the result of evaluating the
> HAVING clause is false, the group is discarded. If the HAVING clause
> is an aggregate expression, it is evaluated across all rows in the
> group. If a HAVING clause is a non-aggregate expression, it is
> evaluated with respect to an arbitrarily selected row from the group.
> The HAVING expression may refer to values, even aggregate functions,
> that are not in the result.

If `HAVING sum(shares) > 0` is included in the query (after the group by), the rows won't be selected in the first place.

I know that is not an answer to the specific question. I *think* `del` takes an index as it's argument. And I have a teacher's voice in the back of my head saying do not mutate a list while it's being iterated.

Comment: What an easy solution! Thanks so much!  Works perfectly